# Stop git from tracking temporary open Microsoft Office files

Tags: git, gitignore

Microsoft Office makes copies of open files, say when you open `abc.xlsx` Excel creates a file called `~$abc.xlsx`, prefaced with a tilde and dollar sign.

When I open an Excel file in my git repository to look at the data, git tracks the new file as a change and I have to take care to avoid committing it.  How can I use a .gitignore file to skip tracking these files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new row to your .gitignore file containing `~$*`.  That will ignore any files beginning with `~$`, the prefix for temporary Microsoft Office files.